# ActionScript 3, 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before dot

Tags: actionscript-3

Can someone help with this please. I'm trying to do a simple coding tutorial and make a guy walk around the screen but I keep running into the same error

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 11, Column 33   1084: Syntax error: 
expecting rightparen before dot.
```

This is the code and I can't seem to find an explanation for what to do. I've followed the tutorial word by word

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Stage;

heroMc.gotoAndStop("FrontBackStill");

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);

function keyDownHandler(keyEvent.KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(keyEvent.keyCode==Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        trace("You pressed right!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `keyDownHandler` the parameters should read:

```
function keyDownHandler(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // ...
}
```

Noting the colon not a period after the `keyEvent`.

This is because you're receiving an event object - of which you're naming `keyEvent`. This is type (`:`) `KeyboardEvent`.